# Qt 5.5 Examples, missing QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, opengl

I'm trying to investigate using off-screen rendering, I would like to explore the examples that are installed with Qt5.5, but so far every attempt to open one of the existing projects and build results in:

```
    QOpenGLWidget: No such file or directory
    #include <QOpenGLWidget>
```

I have not modified the examples in any way, I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: How did you install Qt? 5.5 is not available under 14.04. Are you sure it's using the version you installed and not a system wide one?

Comment: To be honest I can't remember how I got it installed....About Qt Creator show: "Based on Qt 5.2.1 (GCC 4.8.2, 64 bit) Built on Apr 9 2014.  The Qt folder has a 5.5 sub-folder.

Comment: In Tools->Options->Build, is Qt 5.5 found? (Alternative: that smells quite a old Creator installation. Do you have Qt installed locally in your home? Use the Creator you find in there.)

Comment: @peppe, is this instruction for QtCreator?  I get as far as Tools->Options, but I don't see a Build option, it opens an Options dialog and yes "Qt" is installed in my home folder.  According to the options dialog it would appear I'm using 5.2.1 which is also installed "/usr/lib/x86_64-Linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake"

Comment: Which is your problem. You need 5.5. Find Creator in the Qt directory in your home and use that one (Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin/qtcreator).

Comment: Ok, from "About Qt Creator", Qt Creator 3.6.0, Based on Qt 5.5.1 (GCC 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10), 64 bit), all the referenced folders are now correct, however I just tried to build the "cube" example from "Qt/Examples/Qt-5.5/opengl/cube" and I still get: /home/plattens/Qt/Examples/Qt-5.5/opengl/cube/mainwidget.h:46: error: QOpenGLWidget: No such file or directory
 #include <QOpenGLWidget>
                         ^

Comment: Delete the cube.pro.user file that you might have generated before (telling Creator to use the wrong qmake). Then reopen it in Creator.

Comment: Thank you, will try to get everything working today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation of Qt5.5 on Ubuntu 14.04 was not completed correctly, as a result I have two installations 5.2 and 5.5, however thank you to "peppe" I ran Qt Creator for 5.5 and after cleaning up the project by removing the "pro.user" file I was able to progress.